# Using Entity Framework along with Dapper

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, entity-framework-6, dapper

I need guidance on designing data layer for my Web API services. The Web API controllers call the service layer which calls the data layer.

I am planning to use Entity Framework along with Dapper. It might not be a good solution to use both of them together, but I need both. I need EF as it is easier to use and developers in my team are familiar. I need Dapper for performance. So, it will be a mix depending on where the dapper can make significant impact and where we can compromise on being a little late.

When using EF, I wanted to use unit of work with repository for each entity. My repository will be like

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable
{
    private SchoolContext context;

    public StudentRepository(SchoolContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return context.Students.ToList();
    }
}
```

I took that sample code from http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

So, now I wanted to introduce Dapper.

Approach 1:  Initially I thought of having multiple repositories for Dapper and for Entity Framework and I can register the one which I need in my dependency injection container. But in this case, all the methods from `IStudentRepository` interface needs to be implemented in both the EF and Dapper concrete repository classes (if I could do this in Dapper completely, then I don't need EF at all).

Approach 2 : Then I thought about a more ugly approach and it is like exposing a property of `IDbConnection` along with the `DbContext` property (in this case `SchoolContext`) in the above `StudentRepository` class.

So the example would be like

```
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable
{
    private SchoolContext context;
    private IDbConnection Db;

    public StudentRepository(SchoolContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return context.Students.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentsBasedOnSomeComplexCondition()
    {
        //I can use the db property here and work with dapper in this case.
    }
```

(The inclusion of the `IDbConnection` property can be done through an abstract class so as not to repeat the instantiation code of this property and to easily change the connection string in case if needed. I am adding it in the same class for simplicity).

Approach 3 : Now, I thought of separating it further which I again think is an ugly way. Along with `StudentRepository` which has only EF stuff (like the first example), I will have another concrete class called `StudentDapperRepository` which inherits from `StudentRepository`.

All the methods in `StudentRepository` will be changed to `virtual`. So, I will be using `StudentDapperRepository` for my actual data layer and this will have the Dapper implementations where needed and where not needed, it will use the base class `StudentRepository` methods (which is in EF).

I think all my solutions are ugly and adding more complexity and confusion. So, can I have some light into how I can do this.

Comment: Why do you need an extra `IDbConnection` in your repo? Can't you just use the `SchoolContext.Database.Connection` property? That *is* the connection to the underlying database, and it implements `IDbConnection` ...

Comment: Okay, I can use that. But I needed an approach for the design to have both ORM. That is my main concern. Where to mix up Entity and Dapper.